# How to set default namespaces included in Visual Studio 2008 Pro

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When I create a new WebApplication in VS2008, then Default.aspx.cs has default namespaces as follow

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;
```

But I want default namespaces as follow

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Pleae tell me how to alter default namespaces in VS2008 templates

Comment: These are the default `using` directives used to _import_ namespaces to a file. These are not namespaces as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the different Visual Studio [templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky.aspx) as you wish, though I would simply create a new one.

I suggest you read the different [Item Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247069.aspx) topics first.